# Pi 4: Wireless network interface doesn't work if both eth0 and wlan0 are active/connected

Tags: networking, routes, raspbian

I'm running Pi4 with Raspbian for my home automation, and it's connected to its both network interface: eth0 (ethernet) and wlan0 (wifi).

The wlan0 is connected to the network 10.10.10.0/24, which is the VLAN for management. This VLAN is configured on the unifi edgerouter x and uap-ac-lite access point. If only wlan0 is active (i.e, I only use the wifi on the Pi), the Pi should be able to see devices on the other VLANs, for example 10.10.50.0/24 for IoT devices.

However, as the Pi is running Unifi controller, I also need to connect it to the edge router's physical network 192.168.10.0/24 so I can manage the access point. This means, the eth0 is active, which somehow makes VLAN 10.10.50.0/24 inaccessible. I disconnect the ethernet cable and the 10.10.50.0/24 is accessible again.

My best guess is that if both interfaces are enabled, only 1 of them (eth0 in this case) will be used for the default routing. Is it possible to make both routing accessible, depending on the destination networks?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I have found the answer: Simply change priority of the wifi network routing by adding `metric 100` to wlan0 section in `dhcpcd.conf`